# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `fatl`. x could not find function "len"

Tags: r

currently studying R and was faced with the following situation:

```
evalq(pr %<>% mutate(.,
                   fatl = DigFiltr(Close, 1),
                   rftl = DigFiltr(Close, 2),
                   satl = DigFiltr(Close, 3),
                   rstl = DigFiltr(Close, 4)
                   ),
      env)
```

by running this piece of code I get the error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `fatl`.
> x could not find function "len"
> i Input `fatl` is `DigFiltr(Close, 1)`.

With the traceback:

```
> 22. stop(fallback)
> 21. signal_abort(cnd)
> 20. abort(c(cnd_bullet_header(), bullets, i = if (show_group_details) cnd_bullet_cur_group_label()), class = c("dplyr:::mutate_error", "dplyr_error"), error_name = error_name, error_expression =
> error_expression)
> 19. h(simpleError(msg, call))
> 18. .handleSimpleError(function (e) { local_call_step(dots = dots, .index = i, .fn = "mutate", .dot_data = inherits(e,"rlang_error_data_pronoun_not_found")) ...
> 17. rollApply(data = X, fun = function(x) { sum(x * k) }, window = n, minimum = n, align = "right")
> 16. DigFiltr(Close, 1)
> 15. mask$eval_all_mutate(dots[[i]])
> 14. withCallingHandlers({ for (i in seq_along(dots)) { not_named <- (is.null(dots_names) || dots_names[i] == "") ...
> 13. mutate_cols(.data, ...)
> 12. mutate.data.frame(., fatl = DigFiltr(Close, 1), rftl = DigFiltr(Close, 2), satl = DigFiltr(Close, 3), rstl =
> DigFiltr(Close,4))
> 11. mutate(., fatl = DigFiltr(Close, 1), rftl = DigFiltr(Close, 2), satl = DigFiltr(Close, 3), rstl = DigFiltr(Close, 4))
> 10. function_list[[k]](value)
> 9. withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
> 8. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
> 7. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
> 6. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 5. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 4. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
> 3. pr %<>% mutate(., fatl = DigFiltr(Close, 1), rftl = DigFiltr(Close, 2), satl = DigFiltr(Close, 3), rstl = DigFiltr(Close, 4))
> 2. evalq(pr %<>% mutate(., fatl = DigFiltr(Close, 1), rftl = DigFiltr(Close, 2), satl = DigFiltr(Close, 3), rstl = DigFiltr(Close,4)), env)
> 1. evalq(pr %<>% mutate(., fatl = DigFiltr(Close, 1), rftl = DigFiltr(Close, 2), satl = DigFiltr(Close, 3), rstl = DigFiltr(Close,4)), env)
```

The functions before which are called by the error snippet are these (they compile very fine and there's no apparent error in typo or something, at least at my eye)

```
    #-----DigFiltr-------------------------
DigFiltr <- function(X, type = 1){
# X - vector

  fatl <- c( +0.4360409450, +0.3658689069, +0.2460452079, +0.1104506886, -0.0054034585,
             -0.0760367731, -0.0933058722, -0.0670110374, -0.0190795053, +0.0259609206,
             +0.0502044896, +0.0477818607, +0.0249252327, -0.0047706151, -0.0272432537,
             -0.0338917071, -0.0244141482, -0.0055774838, +0.0128149838, +0.0226522218,
             +0.0208778257, +0.0100299086, -0.0036771622, -0.0136744850, -0.0160483392,
             -0.0108597376, -0.0016060704, +0.0069480557, +0.0110573605, +0.0095711419,
             +0.0040444064, -0.0023824623, -0.0067093714, -0.0072003400, -0.0047717710,
             0.0005541115, 0.0007860160, 0.0130129076, 0.0040364019 )
  
  if (type == 1) {k = fatl} 
  
  n <- length(k)
  m <- length(X)
  k <- rev(k)
  
  f <- rollApply(data = X, 
                       fun = function(x) {sum(x * k)},
                       window = n, minimum = n, align = "right")
  while (length(f) < m) { f <- c(NA,f)}
  return(f)
}
```

These are the packages used in the project :

> ```
> require('magrittr')   
> require('dplyr')   
> require('anytime')
> ```

And the rollApply function was from the deprecated rowr package, so it's handwritten :

```
rollApply <- function(data,fun,window=len(data),minimum=1,align='left',progressbar=FALSE,...)
{
  if(minimum>len(data))
    return()
  if(progressbar) {
    if (system.file(package='pbapply')=='')
      stop('Package pbapply required for progress bar.')
    SAPPLY=pbapply::pbsapply
  } else {
    SAPPLY=sapply
  }
  FUN=match.fun(fun)
  if (align=='left')
    result<-SAPPLY(1:(len(data)-minimum+1),function (x) FUN(rows(data,x:(min(len(data),(x+window-1)))),...))
  if (align=='right')
    result<-SAPPLY(minimum:len(data),function (x) FUN(rows(data,max(1,x-window+1):x),...))
  return(result)
}
```

env is a empty object and pr is a dataframe with the following structure :

```
Gmt_time    Open    High     Low   Close Volume
1 12.10.2020 00:00:00.000 1.30298 1.30300 1.30265 1.30279 239.35
2 12.10.2020 00:01:00.000 1.30280 1.30281 1.30268 1.30271 139.30
3 12.10.2020 00:02:00.000 1.30273 1.30285 1.30272 1.30280 209.98
4 12.10.2020 00:03:00.000 1.30281 1.30284 1.30275 1.30281  61.88
5 12.10.2020 00:04:00.000 1.30280 1.30281 1.30273 1.30275  88.94
6 12.10.2020 00:05:00.000 1.30275 1.30275 1.30261 1.30264 112.28
```

Can't find any apparent solution, can any of you guys help?

Comment: what is `env` ? What is `pr`? You need to share your data. Trying using `dput`. Also add the libraries you are using.

Comment: Mr @Edo thank you a lot for your time and eye to make me look into some missing places, alredy solved the problem, it was some functions missing from the old rowr package, wich have a very common name, so I believed they were included in the language. Wish you a great weekend !